# Have image that needs to take up full width on all screen sizes. Zoom in on larger screen to prevent fill bars on sides

Tags: html, css

This is what I have so far

```
<img style="height:auto; overflow-y:hidden; width:100%;" 
src="/static/images/cover.jpg">
```

This does not seems to solve the problem. I have tried to add

```
 will-change: transform, top;
```

Desired Output:

Since the image is not 1920px wide on the larger sized monitors it receives fill bars on the sides. I'd like this image to instead always go to the full width of the window. (even when zooming and out) And when the browser window becomes smaller the image will get cropped in. I'd also like to be able to control the image by having the bottom of the image visible in all cases. Aspect ratio should be maintained.

Comment: instead of `%` try `vw` instead as that will take entire port width

Comment: @Aaqib Doesnt help.

Comment: Hi questnofinterest. While editing this question, I notice that you received two answers on the same day, but you do not seem to have responded. While it is not strictly mandatory to interact with helpful folks, it is sure nice to. Did you just forget in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you’re wanting the imagine to go outside the bounds of the container. You have two options really;

a) take the image outside of the container that is restricting the image from being 100% width of the screen. Note: 100% width is merely 100% width of the container, not of the viewport

b) use JavaScript to detect the distance from either side of the image to the edge of the window and set a negative margin to ‘pull’ the image towards the edges of the window

Answer (score 0):

why not using `background` instead of `<img>`? See below:

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url('http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg') bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

1. We set a background using `background: url('img/path-to-image.png') (...);`
2. We want to always see the bottom of the image so we use `background: (...) bottom`
3. The background will cover the entire div using `background-size: cover;`
4. Our div should fit the entire user screen, we do it thanks to: `height: 100vh; width: 100vw;`

   > vw, vh: Respectively these are 1/100th of the width of the viewport, and 1/100th of the height of the viewport. Again, these are not as widely supported as rems.
   > [CSS units - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units)